# Parsing values of string in another object angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some string like this

```
 const resultComing ='access_token=test&token_type=bearer&state=state&expires_in=43199&scope=test';
```

I need to passed to object that will look like this

```
const result: any = {
  access_token: test,
  token_type: bearer,
  state: state,
  expires_in: 43199,
  scope: test
};
```

I have tried like this

```
const result: any = resultComing.split('&').reduce(function (result: any, item: string) {
  const parts = item.split('=');
  result[parts[0]] = parts[1];
}, {});
```

But i got error, **TypeError: Cannot set property 'token_type' of undefined**

Comment: [Does this work for you?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=18&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwgVwDZQMIgLYEswDmMAvAOQCGwwSEA+lCANYJjFRJQBkDzY9AngAcExAEYJyiOJ2jl2xWe04IAHoNyI6+YgBYAzAEYAnEZmhhbDqQDcAKFuoEsEKIBWALhjkw-EjADeAL52jrCC5BoQfppomDj4BAB0EIKouFAAFKScpACUdrYAZiBwMBmhMOEaMCCFlRFwELkBtjBtMBXhcFBRxPUayanpWWT5re0urgDaXT1TAAwAuot+sxBTBot2gfagkCCOiaggBBmT+UA) It's a little more readable and does exactly what you want.

Comment: This is good solution, can you write an answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesnt work because as Niet said, you dont return anything from the [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function and so the next time it iterates over it, `result` will be undefined.

To fix it, simply return the result at the end:

```
const result: any = resultComing.split('&').reduce(function (result: any, item: string) {
    const parts = item.split('=');
    result[parts[0]] = parts[1];
    return result;
}, {});
```

If you don't want the arrow function, you can also go over your pairs with a simple loop:

```
let obj: any = {};
let pairs = resultComing.split('&');

for (let pair of pairs) {
    let parts = pair.split('=');
    obj[parts[0]] = parts[1];
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwgVwDZQMIgLYEswDmMAvDAOQCGwwSEA+lCANYJjFRJQBkjLYDATwAOCYgCMEFRHC7QKHYnI5cEADyG5E9fMQAsAZgCMATmOzQI9pzIBuAFB3UCWCDEArAFwwKYASRgA3gC+9k6wQhSaEP5aaJg4+AQAdBBCqLhQABRkXGQAlPZ2AGYgcDCZYTARmjAgRVWRcBB5gXYw7TCVEXBQ0aTVcClpGdnE+fYdte4A2t290wAMALpL-nMQ04ZL9kEOoJAgTkmoIASZrm4FDnb70PBIcV4+fqSx6Fh4hEPpWTn5SYgACbIGiZIrIMDAKC4cDlN5QJ6+AA0MAyCGwXmgcESLQCbQ6t3CUl6-jR2G+IzIYyuk3hs2JG2Wq36DM223x7UQUGQcDA9xQ6B2KOCVxu4AghwQx1OmXhBSAA)

Answer (score 0):

The result array you are calling within the following line is never intitiated and therefore.

```
result[parts[0]] = parts[1];
```

try the following:

```
const result: any = {};
resultComing.split('&').reduce(function (result: any, item: string) {
  const parts = item.split('=');
  result[parts[0]] = parts[1];
}, {});
```

Comment: `result` is the "current" parameter in the `reduce()` call.

Comment: non-arrow functions are forbidden (only-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 0):

`.reduce()`'s callback expected something to be `return`ed.

```
const [k,v] = item.split("=");
result[k] = v;
return result;
```

This is why the error you get is only on the *second* key. For the first key, it passes your "initial" value of `{}` into the function and works just fine, but since the function doesn't `return` anything then the second call has `undefined` and you can't set properties on that.